# PHP LDAP Authenticated as

Tags: php, ldap

is this possible to show who is authenticated after the login ?

my code contains the login and is working:

html:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    User:
    <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
    Pwd:
    <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php 

$ldapServer = 'ldap://myServer';
$ldapPort = myPort;
$username = $_POST['username']."@myDomain.local";
$password = $_POST['password'];

$connect = ldap_connect($ldapServer, $ldapPort) or die("Connection failed!.");
ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if (@ldap_bind($connect, $username, $password)) {
   echo "Authenticated";
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

when i start the ldp.exe programm it shows me the 
ldp.exe:

```
0 = ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_ENCRYPT, 1)
res = ldap_bind_s(ld, NULL, &NtAuthIdentity, NEGOTIATE (1158)); // v.3
    {NtAuthIdentity: User='myUserName'; Pwd=<unavailable>; domain = 'myDomain.local'}
Authenticated as: 'MYDOMAIN\myUser'.
```

the question is how can i extract and render it to the html page who i correctly autheticated.

Comment: Surely you can just `echo $username` to show who is logged in?  Store that value in `$_SESSION` to reference it in other pages.

Answer (score 1):

for the record: solution for my problem:
I put the code between the if statement

```
$filter = "(samAccountName=$user)";
    $search = ldap_search($connect, $base_dn, $filter);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $search);
    echo "Logged In";
    for($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
        if($info['count'] > 1) break;
        echo "<p>Hello, <strong> ". $info[$i]["sn"][0] .", " . $info[$i]["givenname"][0] ."</strong><br /> (" . $info[$i]["samaccountname"][0] .")</p>\n";
    }
```